# inserting data in mysql using GET method and populating text field on client side

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Below is my code for the admin panel where I have used ajax for populating the text field from selected drop down menu on the client side. Please suggest me solutions for the two issues:

Form 'issue': On submitting, it should insert data into the database. But I think there's some problem with the $_GET['submit1'].

Form 'return_form': I m trying to populate the text box 'charges' on the basis of value of 'days' text box entered. But no value obtained either by using 'onfocus()' or 'onblur()'.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function func1()
        {
            var req;
            try
            {
                req= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                try
                {
                    req= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        req= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        alert("Something went wrong..!!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            req.onreadystatechange= function()
                                    {
                                        if(req.readyState==4)
                                        {
                                            var result= req.responseText;
                                            var string= result.split('-');
                                            document.issue.cost.value= string[0]; 
                                            document.issue.rent.value= string[1];
                                        }
                                    }
            var book= document.getElementById('book').value;
            var app_query= "?book="+book;
            req.open("GET","issue_form.php"+app_query,true);
            req.send(null);
        }

        function func2()
        {
            var req;
            try
            {
                req= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                try
                {
                    req= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        req= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        alert("Something went wrong..!!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            req.onreadystatechange= function()
                                    {
                                        if(req.readyState==4)
                                        {
                                            var result= req.responseText;
                                            var string= result.split('-');
                                            document.return_form.iss_yr.value= string[0];
                                            var month= string[1];
                                            /*switch(month)
                                            {
                                                case 01: month="Jan";
                                                         break;
                                                case 02: month="Feb";
                                                         break;
                                                case 03: month="Mar";
                                                         break;
                                                case 04: month="Apr";
                                                         break;
                                                case 05: month="May";
                                                         break;
                                                case 06: month="June";
                                                         break;
                                                case 07: month="July";
                                                         break;
                                                case 08: month="Aug";
                                                         break;
                                                case 09: month="Sep";
                                                         break;
                                                case 10: month="Oct";
                                                         break;
                                                case 11: month="Nov";
                                                         break;
                                                case 12: month="Dec";
                                                         break;
                                                default: alert("Invalid...!!");
                                            }*/
                                            document.return_form.iss_mnth.value= month;
                                            document.return_form.iss_date.value= string[2];
                                            document.return_form.cost2.value= string[3]; 
                                            document.return_form.rent2.value= string[4];
                                        }
                                    }
            var book= document.getElementById('books').value;
            var app_query= "?book="+book;
            req.open("GET","return_form.php"+app_query,true);
            req.send(null);
        }

        function func3()
        {
            var req;
            try
            {
                req= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                try
                {
                    req= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        req= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                        alert("Something went wrong..!!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            req.onreadystatechange= function()
                                    {
                                        if(req.readyState==4)
                                        {
                                            var result= req.responseText;
                                            document.return_form.charges.value= result;
                                        }
                                    }
            var rent= document.getElementById('rent2').value;
            var days= document.getElementById('days').value;
            var app_query= "?rent2="+rent+"days="+days;
            req.open("GET","calc_charges.php"+app_query,true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    include('connect.php');
?>

    <div class="style1">
        <form name="issue" action="" method="get" style="margin-top:25%">

            <fieldset style="width:700px; height:400px; margin-left:25%; border-color:#044146;">
                <legend style="font-size:24px; font-family:'Comic Sans MS', cursive; font-weight:bolder; color:#0D5C6A;">Issue A Book</legend>

                <table align="center" border="1" class="style2" height="270px" width="500px" style="margin-top:50px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Book: </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="book" id="book" onchange="func1()" style="width:250px;">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">---select---</option>
                                    <?php
                                        $query1= mysql_query("select book_name from books");
                                        while($books= mysql_fetch_array($query1))
                                        {
                                            echo '<option>';
                                            echo $books['book_name'];
                                            echo '</option>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date of Issue: </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="issue_date" id="issue_date">
                                <option value="DD">DD</option>
                                <option value="01">01</option>
                                <option value="02">02</option>
                                <option value="03">03</option>
                                <option value="04">04</option>
                                <option value="05">05</option>
                                <option value="06">06</option>
                                <option value="07">07</option>
                                <option value="08">08</option>
                                <option value="09">09</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                                <option value="24">24</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="26">26</option>
                                <option value="27">27</option>
                                <option value="28">28</option>
                                <option value="29">29</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="31">31</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="issue_month" id="issue_month">
                                <option value="MM">MM</option>
                                <option value="01">Jan</option>
                                <option value="02">Feb</option>
                                <option value="03">Mar</option>
                                <option value="04">Apr</option>
                                <option value="05">May</option>
                                <option value="06">Jun</option>
                                <option value="07">Jul</option>
                                <option value="08">Aug</option>
                                <option value="09">Sep</option>
                                <option value="10">Oct</option>
                                <option value="11">Nov</option>
                                <option value="12">Dec</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="issue_year" id="issue_year">
                                <option value="YYYY">YYYY</option>
                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                                <option value="2024">2024</option>
                                <option value="2025">2025</option>
                                <option value="2026">2026</option>
                                <option value="2027">2027</option>
                                <option value="2028">2028</option>
                                <option value="2029">2029</option>
                                <option value="2030">2030</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cost: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cost" style="width:240px;" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rent_per_day: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="rent" style="width:240px;" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit" class="style5" /></td>
                    </tr>    
                </table>

            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <form name="return_form" action="" method="get" style="margin-top:5%">

            <fieldset style="width:700px; height:490px; margin-left:25%; border-color:#044146;">
                <legend style="font-size:24px; font-family:'Comic Sans MS', cursive; font-weight:bolder; color:#0D5C6A;">Return A Book</legend>

                <table align="center" border="1" class="style2" height="350px" width="500px" style="margin-top:50px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Book: </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="books" id="books" onchange="func2()" style="width:250px;">
                                <option value="" selected="selected">---select---</option>
                                    <?php
                                        $query2= mysql_query("select book_issued from member_activity_log");
                                        while($books= mysql_fetch_array($query2))
                                        {
                                            echo '<option>';
                                            echo $books['book_issued'];
                                            echo '</option>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date of Issue: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="iss_date" style="width:40px;" readonly="readonly" />
                            <input type="text" name="iss_mnth" style="width:40px;" readonly="readonly" />
                            <input type="text" name="iss_yr" style="width:45px;" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cost: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cost2" style="width:240px;" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rent_per_day: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="rent2" style="width:240px;" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date of Return: </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="return_date" id="return_date">
                                <option value="DD">DD</option>
                                <option value="01">01</option>
                                <option value="02">02</option>
                                <option value="03">03</option>
                                <option value="04">04</option>
                                <option value="05">05</option>
                                <option value="06">06</option>
                                <option value="07">07</option>
                                <option value="08">08</option>
                                <option value="09">09</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                                <option value="24">24</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="26">26</option>
                                <option value="27">27</option>
                                <option value="28">28</option>
                                <option value="29">29</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="31">31</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="return_month" id="return_month">
                                <option value="MM">MM</option>
                                <option value="01">Jan</option>
                                <option value="02">Feb</option>
                                <option value="03">Mar</option>
                                <option value="04">Apr</option>
                                <option value="05">May</option>
                                <option value="06">Jun</option>
                                <option value="07">Jul</option>
                                <option value="08">Aug</option>
                                <option value="09">Sep</option>
                                <option value="10">Oct</option>
                                <option value="11">Nov</option>
                                <option value="12">Dec</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="return_year" id="return_year">
                                <option value="YYYY">YYYY</option>
                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                                <option value="2024">2024</option>
                                <option value="2025">2025</option>
                                <option value="2026">2026</option>
                                <option value="2027">2027</option>
                                <option value="2028">2028</option>
                                <option value="2029">2029</option>
                                <option value="2030">2030</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>No. of Days: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="days" style="width:240px;" onblur="func3()"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Charges: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="charges" style="width:240px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit" class="style5" /></td>
                    </tr>    
                </table>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
    $reg_no= $_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_GET['submit1']))
    {
        $book_name= $_GET['book'];
        $dd= $_GET['issue_date'];
        $mm= $_GET['issue_month'];
        $yyyy= $_GET['issue_year'];
        $date= $yyyy."-".$mm."-".$dd;
        $cost= $_GET['cost'];
        $rent_per_day= $_GET['rent'];
        $insert_query= mysql_query("insert into member_activity_log(book_issued,date_of_issue,cost,rent_per_day) values('".$book_name."','".$date."','".$cost."','".$rent_per_day."') where reg_no='$reg_no'");
        if($insert_query)
        {
            header("Location: member_activity_log.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error...!!";
        }
    }
?>    


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show us some code. You know how it is structured, but we unluckily don't :(

Comment: can you please provide the code??

Comment: first make your question title right .. second show some sample code so that people can suggest ..

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I have edited the post. Please review it.

Comment: well.. that's so confusing sir... First of all, you're only listening to submit1? second, you should rather check if the **form** has been submitted, not the **input**, so it's rather: `if (isset($_GET['issue']));` apart from that, are you aware that this script is HIGHLY vulnerable to sql injections? you should sanitize the strings and values that you're passing, expecially if you're passing them through the GET method. Check out PDO and mysqli_* operators instead of using mysql_*. Anyway, try changing the isset like that and tell us is something goes better :)

Comment: @briosheje: thanks for your suggestion :). since I am new to php, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user152: for instance, just try to replace this: `if(isset($_GET['submit1']))` with this: `if (isset($_GET['issue']))` and check if something happens ;)

Comment: @briosheje: I sorted out the problem and it is working now. Thanks anyways..!! :)